# Update the associations objects for many-to-many-through setup in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations

I have the following models in a Rails 4 application:

```
Appointment
   has_many :schedulables
   has_many :services, through: :schedulables

Service
   has_many :schedulables
   has_many :appointments, through: :schedulables

Schedulable
   belongs_to :service
   belongs_to :appointment
```

In the view (a calendar js component) side I have a POST request (AJAX call) to update an appointment with the list of services the appointment has. The list is set as a string (named "service_ids") containing the IDs of the services separated by comma - something like: "1,2,3".

What is the best way in Rails to update the list of schedulables for an appointment given the input "service_ids" mentioned above? Or any different option to post the list of services to update the "schedulables" under the appointment object instance.

Note: For the creation of the appointment with the related schedulables instances I have the following:

```
@service_ids = params[:service_ids].split(',')
@service_ids.each do |service_id|
  @appointment.schedulables.build(:service_id => service_id.to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @appointment.service_ids = params[:service_ids].split(',')
```

Edit 1:

An association declaration generates several methods on your model by using meta programming.
See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

In that case it is

```
other_ids = (id1, id2, id2)
NOTE: other stays for the association name - 'service' in your case
```

Comment: A little description of why this would work would be useful to others finding this question.